# How to coerce list object to type 'double'

Tags: r

I am trying to use an algorithm: which gives me the following error: Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double.

How could I fix this problem?

File 1: digisurv is an Excel file with 3 columns (found here: https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=ec4c3a19213271b8fe51c0aeeb24ed9ddfe3cac45d5c7b211f7e3722f7b33f475e89481b6ea8fba2bde01c00346402ec6b1ee8ac46dfd1fb09728ebbd9fac599)

File 2: risk is an Excel file with 5 columns (found here: https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=1358107a77b523954e578759ec7ecc0d0645cd24ecfab93548edf9c29fe7e8cf1de8cfefe0357322ab2c007ef65e9177da7c1d5ad8cff3f9054af16a80a39e4b)

```
KMdatafile<-"KMdata study2 figA arm1 time1 ne.txt" 
KMdataIPDfile<-"KMdataIPD study2 figA arm1 time1 ne.txt"
tot.events<-"NA"
arm.id<-1
```

```
t.S<-digisurv[,2]
S<-digisurv[,3]

t.risk<-risk[,2]
lower<-risk[,3]
upper<-risk[,4]
n.risk<-risk[,5]
n.int<-length(n.risk)
n.t<- upper[n.int]
```

Here comes the problem:

```
n.censor<- rep(0,(n.int-1))
n.hat<-rep(n.risk[1]+1,n.t)
cen<-rep(0,n.t)
d<-rep(0,n.t)
KM.hat<-rep(1,n.t)
last.i<-rep(1,n.int)
sumdL<-0
```

Which gives me the Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' on the following lines, (in total 5 of the same errors)

```
arm<-rep(arm.id,n.risk[1])
n.hat<-rep(n.risk[1]+1,n.t)
cen<-rep(0,n.t)
d<-rep(0,n.t)
KM.hat<-rep(1,n.t)
```

If you have questions please feel free to ask!

Comment: Your example is not reproducible.  Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: Hi, see here for how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2414988).

Comment: Apply `unlist` to your list first. `as.double(list(list(1,2), list(3,4)))` gives an error, while `as.double(unlist(list(list(1,2), list(3,4))))` works fine.

Comment: Edited it with attaching example Excel files

Comment: Have you check that you are reading well the table ?? If you print n.t, it gives you a numeric value or a character?

Comment: It gives a numeric value, should it give something else?

Comment: Could anyone help me please?